# Video colors reversed (negative) in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, colors, video

What's the fix for negative colors in videos (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)?

Pictures or thumbnails are not effected, only videos.

It does not seem to be a browser problem as videos viewed offline exhibit the color reversal. I have tried Movie Player and VLC media player, the problem occurs in both.

Videos viewed online (youtube) have the color problem AND are compressed horizontally.
Videos still working fine in XP (dual-boot).

I have tried reinstalling Flash Player but so far any video type is effected. My video driver is correct for my ACER X223w monitor.

Note the lovely green skin tone and red leaves! The rest of window is not effected, only the video.

[image]

UPDATE: Installed "YouTube ALL HTML5 2.1.1" per advice on Ubuntuforums.org, chose the option to disable Flash on Youtube, that cleared up the online video problem. Now I need to figure out how to fix the problem when using the offline viewers.

UPDATE: Found that the colors while viewing offline were not negative, just too strong giving that "neon" look. Adjusted saturation, etc., and got close to "normal". Hard to do with VLC, every time I move the mouse, the screen goes black. Similar with Movie Player but I'll figure it out. Probably end up uninstalling VLC as it seems to be a lot of trouble to adjust. Might try some other viewers.

Cancel red alert!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like one of the problems you can work around with options in `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` to disable the broken features.

See
[Flash video appears blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117127/flash-video-appears-blue) and maybe 
[Disable hardware acceleration for Flash player in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/434762/disable-hardware-acceleration-for-flash-player-in-linux).